# map jj to Esc globally on mac

Tags: macos, mac

So, I like vim and use the key mapping `jj` for `Esc`.

Is there some way to on a global level in Mac OS X map `jj` to `Esc`?

I've tried [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.net/) where I can have global key mappings but they don't support mapping of multiple keys (e.g. `jj`) but just mappings of like `ctrl+j`.

*PS. The motivation:*

In [Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/) there's a Vim-plugin. However, because of a short coming of CodeMirror you can't add key mappings with multiple keys (e.g. `jj`). (https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/923)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also like vim! I was looking for something very similar (I use `jk` but some difference).

I figured it out!

> TL;DR You want to use the [Karabiner app](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)

It's a little bit confusing at first but they have tons of options for remapping keys. The one you're looking for is going to involve "simultaneous keys" fortunately there's a search so if you search for "simultaneous" and "escape" you'll find a couple that map to escape:

[image: Karabiner Screenshot]

You'll notice that this doesn't quite fit either of our use cases though...you're looking for `jj` and I'm looking for `jk`. If you're content retraining your muscle memory to `ji` then you're already done. If you'd still like to stick with `jj` though, you're going to have to do a few extra steps.

Fortunately, it's relatively simple to add your own custom remappings as xml files. Your installation of Karabiner should come with a `private.xml` that lives in `/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Karabiner` (should be able to find it quickly with spotlight). That file starts out pretty bare so that you can fill it up with whatever sort of new mappings you want. You can check out the documentation on doing so [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html#privatexml).

For what you want you just wanna replace what's there with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Stephen Custom Keyboard mappings</name>
        <appendix></appendix>

        <item>
            <name>SimultaneousKeyPresses</name>
            <item>
                <name>J and K to escape</name>
                <appendix>(J+K to Escape)</appendix>
                <identifier>private.j_k_to_escape</identifier>
                <autogen>__SimultaneousKeyPresses__ KeyCode::J, KeyCode::K, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Nice! This brings back some memories :) I actually found karabiner aswell and it's a great app! I even tried out the "vim emulation" that existed in karabiner to get the entire OS in vim-ish mode. After a couple of weeks, I gave it up though... too confusing, but a nice idea :)

Comment: @Cotten That looked really interesting to me as well and I was wondering whether it'd be useful or not. I suspect just the ability to finally be able to use vim mode in non-vim editors without having to hit escape all the time will be good enough though!

Comment: yes, it is quite an interesting thing to be able to for instance use vim bindings to write emails. And it kind of worked. The problem for me was that it was very hard to know what mode I was in. There is no fat cursor indicating command-mode, that became a deal breaker after a while. If haven't found it already, there is Vimium as a chrome ext so you e.g. can use j and k for scrolling... pretty nice :)

Comment: Note that Karabiner works with Mac OS X versions through 10.11 "El Capitan".  For 10.12 "Sierra" and 10.13 "High Sierra", you'll need Karabiner Elements which works differently and has a different configuration format, so these instructions won't work as-is.  I'm pretty sure this should still be possible with Karabiner Elements but I haven't yet figured out how...